# I had a bunch of notes in my account. Where did they go?

Tags: ubuntu-one, notes

Had a bunch of notes synced originally from Tomboy. I still see pics that were attached, but I don't see the content of those notes any longer.

Comment: What did you do since it last work?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, [notes are not accessible from the web interface](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/02/05/an-important-note-about-notes/). You will still be able to view (and sync) them from within Tomboy.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, Ubuntu One notes sync has been discontinued.

http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2013/02/04/notification-about-notes/