# Where did the notes feature go?

Tags: ubuntu-one, notes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I had a bunch of notes in my account. Where did they go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108572/i-had-a-bunch-of-notes-in-my-account-where-did-they-go)

I had been using the notes feature in the web interface of one.ubuntu.com.

I no longer see that Notes feature in the interface.  Have my notes been deleted?

I had important information there that can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Your notes are not deleted, Ubuntu One has removed notes web view.

For more on this, [take a look at the Official Ubuntu One Blog post on the topic.](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/02/05/an-important-note-about-notes/)