# Accessing synced Tomboy notes online.

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I had a bunch of notes in my account. Where did they go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108572/i-had-a-bunch-of-notes-in-my-account-where-did-they-go)

Where can I access synced tomboy notes online?

I can not see Notes in the Ubuntu One web interface.

Comment: You can still view your notes but not via a web browser (online), you just have to install tomboy notes and synchronize your notes.

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer possible, unfortunately. See [the U1 post on the subject](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/02/05/an-important-note-about-notes/).